# Database not able to startup showing control file is inconsistent with another

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, restore, rman

Our windows server 2008 R2 is shutdown due to power failure. When I am trying to startup Oracle 11g database its shows an error.

```
SQL> startup
ORA-01081: cannot start already-running ORACLE - shut it down first
SQL> startup mount
ORA-01081: cannot start already-running ORACLE - shut it down first
SQL> shut immediate
ORA-01507: database not mounted


ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup mount
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 3206836224 bytes
Fixed Size                  2180024 bytes
Variable Size            2415922248 bytes
Database Buffers          771751936 bytes
Redo Buffers               16982016 bytes
ORA-00214: control file 'D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL01.CTL'
version 145627 inconsistent with file
'D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\CONTROL02.CTL' version 145625
```

Can any one help me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried below steps and recovered control file from RMAN Backup. it works successfully...

```
SQL>shutdown abort;

ORACLE instance shut down.

SQL> startup nomount

ORACLE instance started.
Total System Global Area 3206836224 bytes
Fixed Size                  2180024 bytes
Variable Size            2415922248 bytes
Database Buffers          771751936 bytes
Redo Buffers               16982016 bytes
SQL>
```

====create pfile='c:/initnew.ora' from spfile;

```
SQL> create pfile='c:\p.txt' from spfile;

File created.

shutdown abort;

ORACLE instance shut down.
```

-----Edit the pfile and delete the controlfile 02 from controlfiles parameter

-----Then boot the system from newly created pfile

```
SQL> startup mount pfile='c:\p.txt';

SQL>rman target /

RMAN>restore controlfile from autobackup;

RMAN> quit

SQL>shut immediate

SQL>startup mount;

ORACLE instance started.
Total System Global Area 3206836224 bytes
Fixed Size                  2180024 bytes
Variable Size            2415922248 bytes
Database Buffers          771751936 bytes
Redo Buffers               16982016 bytes
ORA-00214: control file
'D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\CONTROL02.CTL' version 145625
inconsistent with file 'D:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL01.CTL' version 144010

SQL> shut immediate
ORA-01507: database not mounted


ORACLE instance shut down.

SQL>startup force mount pfile='c:\p.txt';

ORACLE instance started.
Total System Global Area 3206836224 bytes
Fixed Size                  2180024 bytes
Variable Size            2415922248 bytes
Database Buffers          771751936 bytes
Redo Buffers               16982016 bytes
Database mounted.
SQL>host rman target /

RMAN>recover database;

RMAN> alter database open resetlogs;

database opened.
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to resolve this by copying `CONTROL01.CTL` over `CONTROL02.CTL` since the first one has a higher version number. Make a copy of `CONTROL02.CTL` in case it does not work

Comment: I tried to copying 'CONTROL01.CTL' over CONTROL02.CTL' but when startup database it's showing an error like ,
    'ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel'  
    'Process ID: 3416'  
    'Session ID: 9 Serial number: 3'

Comment: Check the logfiles. There might be something more missing. Are your datafiles also on the D-drive? Perhaps it is corrupt.

Comment: Yes it might be corrupt...So I rollback the changes of controlfile.